# JQuery Stop a click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

While adding a `id` attribute to `a` tag the event associated with it runs automatically. How to stop that from happening.

There is `a` tag with `.show-all` class when I click on that I am adding a id `#hide-all`.Now I want that if I click on that id the data should hide but the problem is it is running on click of `.show-all`.

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/rp5teg49/2/)

Here is the code:

```js
$(".show-all").click(function(e) {
  $(".data").show();
  $(this).text("Hide-All");
  $(this).removeClass("show-all");
  $(this).attr('id', "hide-all");
});
$(document).on('click', "#hide-all", function(e) {
  $(".data").hide();
  $(this).text("Show-All");
  $(this).removeAttr("id");
  $(this).addClass("show-all");
});
```

```css
.data {
  display: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cont">
  <a class="show-all">Show all</a>

  <div class="data">
    <p>
      A1
    </p>
    <p>
      A2
    </p>
    <p>
      A3
    </p>
    <p>
      A4
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try using `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: I tried that its not working

Comment: You removed the class attribute `show-all` thus the click to remove it never worked.

Comment: @t0mm13b But if I don't remove that then on when I click #hide-all first function only works.

Comment: you want to show/hide everytime you click on it ?

Comment: @Pete Its just a sample fiddle.My main purpose is to add the id and then target that id.I have just taken show hide as an example.

Comment: @Pete - your code is throwing exception....

Answer (score 1):

I would just do both bindings on the same element as it is the same thing you will be clicking to do the show and hide:

```js
$(".show-all").click(function(e) {
  var link = $(this); // cache this for better performance
  if (link.text() === 'Show all') {
    $(".data").show();
    link.text("Hide all")
      .removeClass("show-all") // you can chain these, you don't need to put $(this) before each
      .attr('id', "hide-all"); // don't know if you still need this
  } else {
    $(".data").hide();
    link.text("Show all")
      .removeAttr("id")
      .addClass("show-all");
  }
});
```

```css
.data {
  display: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cont">
  <a class="show-all">Show all</a>

  <div class="data">
    <p>
      A1
    </p>
    <p>
      A2
    </p>
    <p>
      A3
    </p>
    <p>
      A4
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update**

As you have said that this is only an example and you would need to rebind - the only way to do this is unbind previous events or use `.one` so you only bind one click event and rebind a new event at the point of clicking:

```js
bindShow();

function bindShow() {
  $(".show-all").one('click', function(e) { // only bind one click - as it will change to a hide once clicked
    $(".data").show();
    $(this)
      .text("Hide all")
      .removeClass("show-all")
      .attr('id', "hide-all");
      
      bindHide();
  });
}

function bindHide() {
  $("#hide-all").one('click', function(e) {
    $(".data").hide();
    $(this)
      .text("Show all")
      .removeAttr("id")
      .addClass("show-all");
    
    bindShow();
  });
}
```

```css
.data {
  display: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cont">
  <a class="show-all">Show all</a>

  <div class="data">
    <p>
      A1
    </p>
    <p>
      A2
    </p>
    <p>
      A3
    </p>
    <p>
      A4
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its just a sample fiddle.My main purpose is to add the id and then target that id.I have just taken show hide as an example.

Comment: I am not looking for show and hide.I want to target the attr id.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to hide/show your `<div class="data">`  you can just use `.toggle()` and compare the text content of the `.show-all` class

```js
$(".show-all").click(function(e) {
  $(".data").toggle();  
  if ($(this).text() == "Show-All"){
    $(this).text("Hide-All")
  }
  else if ($(this).text() == "Hide-All"){
    $(this).text("Show-All")
  }
  
});
```

```css
.data {
  display: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cont">
  <a class="show-all">Show-All</a>

  <div class="data">
    <p>
      A1
    </p>
    <p>
      A2
    </p>
    <p>
      A3
    </p>
    <p>
      A4
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its just a sample fiddle.My main purpose is to add the id and then target that id.I have just taken show hide as an example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a toogle function:

```
$('.toggle).on('click', function(e) {
    $(".data").toggle();
});
```

EDIT:

The problem is that you have already attached the event to the element. Even if you then change the class/id of the element, the event will stay attached.

But you could store the current status in a variable:

```
  var status = 0
  $(".btn").on("click", function() {
    if (status === 0) {
      $(this).html("Send Event 2");
      $("#output").html("Received Event 1");
      status = 1;
    } else {
      $(this).html("Send Event 1");
      $("#output").html("Received Event 2");
      status = 0;
    }
  });
```

See this Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/bEn4q0RhrotEuo3RoaDa?p=preview

If you don't like the idea with the variable you can set a flag in the the data attribute of the link:

```
<a href="#" class=".btn" data-status="0">
```

You can then change the data-status attribute with jQuery on each click.

Comment: Its just a sample fiddle.My main purpose is to add the id and then target that id.I have just taken show hide as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are
https://jsfiddle.net/rp5teg49/3/

```js
$(".show-all").click(function(e) {
  $(".data").toggle('fast');
  if ($(this).text() === "Hide-All") {
    $(this).text("Show-All");
  } else {
    $(this).text("Hide-All");
  }
});
```

```css
.data {
  display: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cont">
  <a class="show-all">Show all</a>

  <div class="data">
    <p>
      A1
    </p>
    <p>
      A2
    </p>
    <p>
      A3
    </p>
    <p>
      A4
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Because when you add event, 2 events are call

```
$(".data").hide(); 
$(".data").show();
```

You can console log in 2 event and see what happend

Comment: Its just a sample fiddle.My main purpose is to add the id and then target that id.I have just taken show hide as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```js
$(document).on('click',".show-all",function(e) {
  $(".data").show();
  $(this).text("Hide-All");
  $(this).removeClass("show-all");
  $(this).attr('id', "hide-all");
});
$(document).on('click', "#hide-all", function(e) {
  $(".data").hide();
  $(this).text("Show-All");
  $(this).removeAttr("id");
  $(this).addClass("show-all");
});
```

```css
.data {
  display: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cont">
  <a class="show-all">Show all</a>

  <div class="data">
    <p>
      A1
    </p>
    <p>
      A2
    </p>
    <p>
      A3
    </p>
    <p>
      A4
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
   

 $(".show-all").click(function(e) {
    if( $(this).attr('id')!='hide-all'){
    $(this).text("Hide-All");
      $(this).removeClass("show-all");
      $(this).attr('id', "hide-all");
      
      $(".data").show();
      }
    else{
   $(".data").hide();
   $(this).text("Show-All");
   $(this).removeAttr("id");
   $(this).addClass("show-all");

}
          });
```

```css
.data {
  display: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cont">
  <a class="show-all">Show all</a>

  <div class="data">
    <p>
      A1
    </p>
    <p>
      A2
    </p>
    <p>
      A3
    </p>
    <p>
      A4
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```